# d3js svg foreignObject overlay chart does not render in internet explorer - any alternative?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have two directives to create charts. One directive is for the background chart and another directive is for overlay charts. It means there is one chart which is on background and few charts which are overlay-ed on top the the first chart (MainChart).  Please have a look at the following image.

[image]

The main chart is always visible and the subcharts are visible whenever the drop down arrow is clicked as shown into the image. 
The sub charts are created using "foreignObject" in d3js and SVG. This all works fine in chrome and FF. However it does not render in IE11 and I need to support it somehow. Is there any alternative available for support it without doing much code changes?

Comment: This is not a bug: IE never supported `foreignObject` and never will: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject . *"Is there any alternative available for support it without doing much code changes?"* No. You'll have to drop it and refactor all your code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there anyway I can achieve the same behavior as shown into the image without using foreignObjects?

Comment: Just use SVG elements.